# Auto-remove data populated from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have data copied to Sheet1 from Sheet2 based on the following code:

```
Sub UpdateList()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
End Sub
```

Here’s my issue:
Source data on Sheet2 is a dynamic list.  If I add new data, the above code works wonderfully populating new data to Sheet1.  However, if data is deleted from Sheet2 (it’s sourced from an ODBC query) the “old” data remains on Sheet1.

I’m stumped for a clean and automated way to remove the old data from Sheet1 other than repetitious striking of the delete key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the Data is stored in column A, just input this:

```
Sub UpdateList()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet1").columns("A").clear
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
    End Sub
```

every time its updated, the column should be cleaned and the values re-entered with the new data.

Comment: That's the trick...I opted to use ClearContents instead of Clear to retain target sheet formatting, but this worked perfectly!